# How to make sure list defined in class variable objects are not shared across different instances?

Tags: python, metaclass

I have the following:

```py
class Loop:
    def __init__(self, group_class: Type[SegmentGroup], start: str, end: str):
        self.group_class = group_class
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

        self._groups: List[SegmentGroup] = []
   
   def from_segments(self, segments):
       self._groups = []  # have to clear so this is not shared among other `Article` instances
       for segment in segments:
            group = self.group_class()
            if some_conditions_are_valid and after_have_populated_group:
                 self._groups.append(group)


class SegmentGroupMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        exclude = set(dir(type))

        components: Dict[str, str] = {}
        loops: Dict[str, str] = {}

        for k, v in attrs.items():
            if k in exclude:
                continue

            if isinstance(v, Segment):
                components[v.unique_tag] = k
            elif isinstance(v, Loop):
                loops[v.start] = k

        attrs.update(__components__=components, __loops__=loops)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class SegmentGroup(metaclass=SegmentGroupMetaClass):
    def from_segments(self, ...):
        """May call `Loop.from_segments`
```

And then I have:

```py
class Topic(SegmentGroup):
    infos = Segment("CAV")
    ...


class Article(SegmentGroup):
    topics = Loop(Topic, ...)
    ...
```

I have a routine that essentially calls `Article().from_segments(segments)` where `segments` is injected from another service in a loop that creates a new `Article` instance on every new iteration.

As you may have noticed, `Loop._groups` must be properly handled in order to not have its values shared among different `Article` instances. My (hacky) solution works fine if we call `Loop.from_segments` for all iterations, but this is not guaranteed as the `topics` segment loop may be missing in the injected `segments`.

This means that for an `Article` without the `topics` segments, it'll actually use the values from the previous iteration (because `Loop._groups` won't be cleared since `Loop.from_segments` won't be called).

I can think in a way to fix this by clearing `Loop._groups` at `Article.__init__`...

```
class SegmentGroup(metaclass=SegmentGroupMetaClass):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        for loop_label in self.__loops__.values():
            setattr(getattr(self, loop_label), "_groups", [])
```

...but it looks even hackier and non-elegant/less efficient to me.

How would you clear `Loop._groups` for every new `Article` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make sure list defined in class variable objects are not shared across different instances?

**TL;DR**: make so that your class variables instances use the descriptor mechanisms in Python (like the `__get__` method), so that it has control on which instance it is operating at each time.

---

You can make your `Loop` class be a descriptor: this way anytime it is used in an Article instance, Python will get it through its `__get__` method: you can them create a sub-object or a closure that will use a list allocated in the host instance.

In this example, whenever retrieved from an instance (ex. `Article().topics`, this will create a temporary copy of the loop object, and set an `_instance` atribute on it.  Then I promoted the `._groups` attribute in the Loop object itself to be a property (which uses the same `__get__` mechanism under the hood), to store on first access, and then use always, a list on the host instance.All you have to do is to ensure your `Loop` class works well with Python's `copy.copy` - if all its code is what is listed here, it will work nicely.

Also: using `.copy` and not `.deepcopy` ensure the instance-bound Loop that is created will share any other data with the main instance - as well as be lightweight.

```
from copy import copy

class Loop:
    def __init__(self, group_class: Type[SegmentGroup], start: str, end: str):
        self.group_class = group_class
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

        
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        # uses the Python __set_name__ mechanism to automatically know the name 
        # each Loop instance is associated to in a class
        self.name = name
        
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        instance_specific_loop = copy(self)
        instance_specific_loop._instance = instance

    @property
    def _groups(self):
        attr_name = f"_groups_{self.name}"
        if not hasattr(self._instance, attr_name):
            setattr(self._instance, attr_name, [])
        return getattr(self._instance, attr_name)

   
    def from_segments(self, segments):
       for segment in segments:
            group = self.group_class()
            if some_conditions_are_valid and after_have_populated_group:
                 self._groups.append(group)
    
    

class SegmentGroupMetaClass(type):
   ...

class SegmentGroup(metaclass=SegmentGroupMetaClass):
    def from_segments(self, ...):
        """May call `Loop.from_segments"""
        ...
        # it will sork, as soon as it does:
        # self._loop_attribute_name_.from_segments(...) 

class Article(SegmentGroup):
    topics = Loop(Topic, ...)
    ...
```

Comment: No worries at all, it's working now :) Correct me if I'm wrong, but the "magic" comes from `__get__` as we actually deals with a copy of `Loop` and when we call something like `Article.topics._groups` we are essentially calling `Article._groups_topics` - which is unique per `Article`instance, correct? This seems quite clever to me but at the same time it seems we are heavily sacrificing both readability and maintainability. What do you think?

Comment: Yes - Article.topics.groups will go twice through `__get__`  methods: one explicit in the `Loop` object, and the other implicity in the Loop._groups property. 
This kind of long chains of access is essentialy what code like the ones in ORMs and frameworks do - but under the hood. Once it is working and tested, you actually gain on readability, in that your final class (Article in this example), can simply have a Loop instance with shared configuration across all Articles and private data, with nothing to worry about: usually it is a win.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253048/discussion-between-murilo-sitonio-and-jsbueno).

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the `Loop` class to accept a factory function that creates the `_groups` attribute dynamically when it's needed. Now `_groups` will be unique per `Article` instance

The modified version:

```
from typing import List, Type, Callable

class Loop:
    def __init__(self, group_factory: Callable[[], SegmentGroup], start: str, end: str):
        self.group_factory = group_factory
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    @property
    def _groups(self) -> List[SegmentGroup]:
        if not hasattr(self, "_groups_instance"):
            setattr(self, "_groups_instance", [])
        return getattr(self, "_groups_instance")
   
    def from_segments(self, segments):
        self._groups_instance = []
        for segment in segments:
            group = self.group_factory()
            if some_conditions_are_valid and after_have_populated_group:
                self._groups.append(group)

# In your Article class definition, update the Loop definition to:
class Article(SegmentGroup):
    topics = Loop(lambda: Topic(), ...)
    ...
```

Comment: This does not work as it has the same effect. I think you are missing the point that this is already handled -> "_groups attribute is unique for each loop instance". What I'm looking for is a better solution to make sure that the `_groups` attribute is unique for each `Article` instance.

Comment: This looks even hackier than my solution tho... but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `instance` of `Loop` as `Article`'s class attribute, so it's just the same `instance` being passed around (so the same values of `Loop`'s `instance` `_topics` are shared across `instance`s of `Article`). Move `Loop` to `Article`'s `init`:

```
class Article(SegmentGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        self.topics = Loop(Topic, ...)
```

Here `foo` shares the same values for `instance`s `a` and `b` of class `OtherFoo` (because `a` and `b` share the same `instance` of `Foo`):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print(f'init {self.__class__.__name__}')
        self.foo = foo
    
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo

class OtherFoo:
    _foo = Foo([0, 1, 2, 33])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print(f'init {self.__class__.__name__}')

    def print_foo(self):
        pass

a = OtherFoo()
print(a._foo.get_foo())
a._foo.foo[-1] += 10
b = OtherFoo()
print(a._foo.get_foo())
print(b._foo.get_foo())
```

Outputs:

```
init Foo
init OtherFoo
[0, 1, 2, 33]
init OtherFoo
[0, 1, 2, 43]
[0, 1, 2, 43]
```

but not here where `a` and `b` have their own `instance`s of `Foo`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print(f'init {self.__class__.__name__}')
        self.foo = foo
    
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo

class OtherFoo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print(f'init {self.__class__.__name__}')
        self._foo = Foo([0, 1, 2, 33])

    def print_foo(self):
        pass

a = OtherFoo()
print(a._foo.get_foo())
a._foo.foo[-1] += 10
b = OtherFoo()
print(a._foo.get_foo())
print(b._foo.get_foo())
```

Outputs:

```
init OtherFoo
init Foo
[0, 1, 2, 33]
init OtherFoo
init Foo
[0, 1, 2, 43]
[0, 1, 2, 33]
```

Comment: I know that the problem is due the fact that multiple instances are sharing the same `Loop._groups` list and that defining it at instance level would do trick, however this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (I can think of DRY and dependency inversion principle, for instance). That's why I use "class variable" in the question's title. Thanks a lot anyways!